# How to reset a palette on Java NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

While working on Java (netbeans) I accidentally deleted the code generation palette, how can I reset it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not called "code generator" - it's the "Properties window.

You can re-display it using

```
Window -> IDE Tools -> Properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using NetBeans 8.2 and accidentally deleted the jPanel. Here is what I did to reset it.

`Right Click one of the Containers -> Click Reset`

Simple as that. Hope it helps.  below is the Link of my screen shot. . .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On palette Then you find the option called Reset Palette